# Iterate array of struct using double pointer and access elements using double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a nested struct car

```
struct employee{
    int id;
    unsigned int department_id;
    char initials;
};

struct car{
    int number;
    unsigned int tagged;
    struct employee emp;
};
```

Then I have an object of the struct car

```
struct car carObj[5] = {
    {1, 1, {11, 111,'c'}},
    {2, 0, {22, 222, 'd'}},
    {3, 1, {33, 333, 'e'}},
    {4, 1, {44, 444, 'f'}},
    {5, 0, {55, 555, 'g'}}
};
```

Next I have a pointer to the struct car

```
struct car *carPtr;
```

This "carPtr" pointer I have to fill with the various elements from the object carObj.
I will allocate a new memory for each object of the car and copy the array element in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee{
    int id;
    unsigned int department_id;
    char initials;
};

struct car{
    int number;
    unsigned int tagged;
    struct employee emp;
};

struct car carObj[5] = {
    {1, 1, {11, 111,'c'}},
    {2, 0, {22, 222, 'd'}},
    {3, 1, {33, 333, 'e'}},
    {4, 1, {44, 444, 'f'}},
    {5, 0, {55, 555, 'g'}}
};

struct car *carPtr;

void fillData(struct car **t)
{
    int cnt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     cnt++;
     if(*t == NULL)
     {
        *t = calloc(cnt, sizeof(struct car));
     }
     else
     {
        *t = realloc(*t, (cnt*sizeof(struct car)));
     }

     memcpy(& ______, &carObj[i], sizeof(struct car));

        printf("%s(): number = %d, tagged = %d, id = %d, department = %d, initials = %c\n", __func__, ____.number, _____.tagged, ____.emp.id,  ____.emp.department_id, ______.emp.initials);
    }    
}

int main()
{   
    sendData(&carPtr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    printf("%s(): number = %d, tagged = %d, id = %d, department = %d, initials = %c\n", __func__, carPtr[i].number, carPtr[i].tagged, carPtr[i].emp.id,  carPtr[i].emp.department_id, carPtr[i].emp.initials);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Question how do I access the access the individual elements using the double pointer?
In memcpy above I have marked a blank "____ ". What statement I need to write there to access the recently allocated pointer?
In the printf what statement I should write to access the elements of the pointer.

Comment: `memcpy(*t, &carObj[i], sizeof(struct car));` and `(*t)->number`, etc.

Comment: Even simpler, structs are assignable lvalues, : `**t = carObj[i];` (but it makes no sense to reallocate and always assign to the first element)

Comment: `(*t)[i] = carObj[i];` .  Also, if you know the number of items, why not just allocate enough space for all of them once instead of reallocating repeatedly in the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Jonathan I think in memcpy if we use *t then it will overwrite always the first element address after it has reallocated memory. 
WildPlasser this is a sample code while in real code I have to allocate memory and fill the data in the code.
Dmitri I will not know the number of items in real time environment and also I will not be having the carObj struct in case of which I will have to fill the data myself.

Comment: I think you want `struct employee *emp[];` as employee may use more than one car, and one car can be used by more than one employee. Dynamic allocation and deallocation will be needed

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but there are a few improvements to make:

1. Avoid the use of global variables,
2. Choose a meaningful return type for `fillData()` that will indicate success/failure back in the caller,
3. You know the number of elements before you call `fillData()` so simply allocate once and copy, and
4. Pass the necessary information as parameters to your function.

Declare the variables in the scope where they are needed. For `carObj[]` that would be:

```
int main (void)
{   
  struct car carObj[ ] = {{1, 1, {11, 111,'c'}},    /* avoid global variables */
                          {2, 0, {22, 222, 'd'}},
                          {3, 1, {33, 333, 'e'}},
                          {4, 1, {44, 444, 'f'}},
                          {5, 0, {55, 555, 'g'}}},
    *carPtr = NULL;                                 /* must initialize pointer NULL */
  size_t nelem = sizeof carObj/sizeof *carObj;      /* number of elements */
  ...
```

Since you allocate in `fillData()`, you must have a way to indicate to the calling function whether the allocation succeeded or failed so that can be validated in the caller BEFORE any use is made of the allocated block of memory, e.g.

```
/* choose meaningful return type that indicates success/failure */
struct car *fillData (struct car **t, struct car *obj, size_t nelem)
{
  *t = calloc (nelem, sizeof **t);    /* number of elements known, just allocate */
  
  if (t == NULL) {                    /* valdiate every allocation */
    perror ("calloc-t");
    return NULL;
  }
  
  return memcpy (*t, obj, nelem * sizeof **t);  /* return pointer to allocated block */
}
```

(**note:** by using the dereferenced pointer to set the type-size for the allocation, you will never get it wrong)

As shown above, you know the number of elements `nelem`, so there is no need to loop in `fillData()`, just allocate, validate and copy.

By passing the necessary parameters to `fillData()`, you avoid the need for any globals and by choosing a meaningful return, you have a way to validate whether your block was allocated and filled back in `main()`. Your call in `main()` would be:

```
  if (!fillData (&carPtr, carObj, nelem))           /* validate function return */
    return 1;
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee {
    int id;
    unsigned int department_id;
    char initials;
};

struct car {
    int number;
    unsigned int tagged;
    struct employee emp;
};

/* choose meaningful return type that indicates success/failure */
struct car *fillData (struct car **t, struct car *obj, size_t nelem)
{
  *t = calloc (nelem, sizeof **t);    /* number of elements known, just allocate */
  
  if (t == NULL) {                    /* valdiate every allocation */
    perror ("calloc-t");
    return NULL;
  }
  
  return memcpy (*t, obj, nelem * sizeof **t);  /* return pointer to allocated block */
}

int main (void)
{   
  struct car carObj[ ] = {{1, 1, {11, 111,'c'}},    /* avoid global variables */
                          {2, 0, {22, 222, 'd'}},
                          {3, 1, {33, 333, 'e'}},
                          {4, 1, {44, 444, 'f'}},
                          {5, 0, {55, 555, 'g'}}},
    *carPtr = NULL;                                 /* must initialize pointer NULL */
  size_t nelem = sizeof carObj/sizeof *carObj;      /* number of elements */
  
  if (!fillData (&carPtr, carObj, nelem))           /* validate function return */
    return 1;
  
  // sendData (&carPtr);
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++)                /* output results */
  {
    printf ("%s(): number = %d, tagged = %u, id = %d, department = %d, initials = %c\n",
            __func__, carPtr[i].number, carPtr[i].tagged, carPtr[i].emp.id,
            carPtr[i].emp.department_id, carPtr[i].emp.initials);
  }
  
  free (carPtr);        /* free allocated memory */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/car_employee
main(): number = 1, tagged = 1, id = 11, department = 111, initials = c
main(): number = 2, tagged = 0, id = 22, department = 222, initials = d
main(): number = 3, tagged = 1, id = 33, department = 333, initials = e
main(): number = 4, tagged = 1, id = 44, department = 444, initials = f
main(): number = 5, tagged = 0, id = 55, department = 555, initials = g
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/car_employee
==14725== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14725== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14725== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14725== Command: ./bin/car_employee
==14725==
main(): number = 1, tagged = 1, id = 11, department = 111, initials = c
main(): number = 2, tagged = 0, id = 22, department = 222, initials = d
main(): number = 3, tagged = 1, id = 33, department = 333, initials = e
main(): number = 4, tagged = 1, id = 44, department = 444, initials = f
main(): number = 5, tagged = 0, id = 55, department = 555, initials = g
==14725==
==14725== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14725==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14725==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,124 bytes allocated
==14725==
==14725== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14725==
==14725== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14725== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much David for all your efforts. FYI I will not be knowing the exact number of elements in advance in actual project environment. In real time environment I will receive an object of struct car which I will store in the dynamically allocated pointer. So I have to allocate memory for each car object every time and store the received car info in it.  Assume that the above code is running on server where it will save the car details. The client will everytime send one car info to the server and the server will save it.

Comment: Okay, in that case you must have some way to find the last element (like a sentinel NULL or blank record at the end of the array you pass). There you will iterate allocating and reallocating until you reach the end. It is always better to allocate for some reasonably anticipated number (I generally start at `2` elements and then double each time reallocation is needed). That is a good balance of growth and calls to `realloc()` (`2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, ...`). If reading data from a file, then simply control your read/fill loop with the return of your read-function.

Comment: Exactly. In this case how will I write the first argument of the memcpy() call? And in printfs how will I access the elemts using double pointer?

Comment: In the case of "allocate 1 / send 1", then you need to decide if you need to store anything on the client. If you are just sending and the allocation and saving occurs on the server -- then the server is the only one that needs to allocate. You can just iterate over `carObj[]` calling `sendData()` and then have your code on the server aggregate bytes until a full `struct` is received and then `realloc()` and save in the storage on the server.

Comment: Or, are you thinking by allocating and storing on the client, you will use that as a way to "Serialize" the array and send it to the server?? That isn't optimal, but I guess if your client and server are the same architecture and same compiler, etc.. -- you may avoid padding differences -- BUT -- know for a portable solution, you should actually serialize the struct data to pass to the server. Here your client's job is just to transmit the data, so no `memcpy()` on the client is needed. You will want to search "Serialize Struct Data" on this site.

Comment: A very, very good basic tutorial on networking is [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) (a blt folksy written, but the most up to date walk through of basic networking you will find) It takes you up to how to serialize and discusses some of the current libraries available -- along with showing basic examples of how to approach it -- but pointing you to use an actual serialization library rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am using "memcpy(&   (*t)[cnt-1], &carObj[i], sizeof(struct car));" statement to copy the data. Its working but I am doubtful if this is proper or not.

Comment: You are still a bit confused (but it works). Why? Take a generic `a[i]` in index notation is equivalent to `*(a + i)` in pointer notation. Now apply that to `& (*t)[cnt-1]` which is `& *(*t + cnt - 1)` (where `&` cancels the `*` leaving `*t + cnt - 1`) The same for `&carObj[i]` which is simply `carObj + i`. The fact you needed `[cnt-1]` means you incremented `cnt` too soon.